# Force Code to run on UI Thread from CustomRibbon Excel VSTO add-in

Tags: c#, winforms, excel-addins

I have an Excel VSTO add-in. I have logic where a dataset can be refreshed from the API I am retrieving the data from. The user selects a specific cell in the dataset and clicks a refresh button I have in my Custom Ribbon. During the refresh code block, the thread switches from the UI thread to a worker thread after I make my API call. After retrieving my data, I need to write it to the spreadsheet. In my writing logic, I set `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating` to `false` then back to `true` once I complete my writing. I am getting an exception when setting `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating` back to `true` because I am not on the UI thread, but it works fine setting it to `false`.

Error: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AC472`

How can I force my writing logic to execute on the UI thread from the `CustomRibbon` class?

```
// in CustomRibbon.cs
private async void RefreshActiveDatasetIcon_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    var formula = ExcelReadScheme.GetFormulaFromActiveCell(out Excel.Range formulaCell);

    if (formula is null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No formula was found in the active cell.", "No Formula Found", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        await RefreshDataAsync(formula, formulaCell);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Unexpected error", ex);
    }
}
```

```
// in CustomRibbon.cs
private async Task RefreshDataAsync(Formula Formula, Excel.Range formulaCell)
{
    // switches to worker thread after this call completes.
    string getDataFromListOfSymbols = await SomeApi.GetForwardChartingCurveAsync(formula.MaturityDateStart.Value, formula.MaturityDateEnd.Value, formula.Symbols.Keys).ConfigureAwait(true);

    ExcelWriteScheme.WriteForwardCurveDataToActivatedCell(formula, getDataFromListOfSymbols, formulaCell);
}
```

```
public static void WriteForwardCurveDataToActivatedCell(Formula formula, string forwardCurveResponses, Excel.Range activeCellUponFormOpen)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;

    try
    {
        Excel.Worksheet currentSheet = activeCellUponFormOpen.Worksheet;

        var responses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ForwardCurveResponse>>(forwardCurveResponses);

        // start index at 2 as first column is formula / trade date and second column is maturity date
        var distinctSymbolHeadersWithColumnIndices = responses
            .Select(x => x.Symbol)
            .Distinct()
            .Select((header, index) => new { Header = header, Index = index + 2 + activeCellUponFormOpen.Column })
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Header, item => item.Index);

        currentSheet.Cells[activeCellUponFormOpen.Row, activeCellUponFormOpen.Column + 1].Value = "Maturity Date";
        currentSheet.Cells[activeCellUponFormOpen.Row, activeCellUponFormOpen.Column + 1].Font.Bold = true;
        currentSheet.Cells[activeCellUponFormOpen.Row, activeCellUponFormOpen.Column + 1].wrapText = true;

        foreach (var kvp in distinctSymbolHeadersWithColumnIndices)
        {
            currentSheet.Cells[activeCellUponFormOpen.Row, kvp.Value].Value = kvp.Key;
            currentSheet.Cells[activeCellUponFormOpen.Row, kvp.Value].Font.Bold = true;
        }

        int row = activeCellUponFormOpen.Row + 1;
        bool firstPass = true;
        foreach (var response in responses.OrderByDescending(x => x.SymbolGroup.Count))
        {
            foreach (var group in response.SymbolGroup)
            {
                if (firstPass)
                {
                    currentSheet.Cells[row, activeCellUponFormOpen.Column].Value = group.TradeDate;
                    currentSheet.Cells[row, activeCellUponFormOpen.Column + 1].Value = group.MaturityDate;
                }

                if (group.Value.HasValue)
                {
                    currentSheet.Cells[row, distinctSymbolHeadersWithColumnIndices[response.Symbol]].Value = group.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    currentSheet.Cells[row, distinctSymbolHeadersWithColumnIndices[response.Symbol]].Value = string.Empty;
                }

                row++;
            }

            firstPass = false;

            row = activeCellUponFormOpen.Row + 1;
        }

        activeCellUponFormOpen.Formula = FormatStringForFormulaFunction(formula.FormatInstanceToExcelString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        // Error thrown here
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
    }
}
```